# Inherit from std::exception without changing users code

Tags: c++, api-design

Currently within our API we have our own exception-type `MyException` which does not (neither directly nor indirectly) inherit from `std::exception` or any other type:

```
class MyException {
public:
    MyException(std::string const& message);
    std::string const& GetErrorMessage() const;
private:
    //...stuff, e.g. like the error-message.
};
```

To our customers (and our own developers ) this leads the burden of always adding at least two catch-handler to a try-block:

```
try {
    SomeLibraryFunction();
}
catch (MyException const& e) { std::cerr << e.GetErrorMessage(); }
catch (std::exception const& e) { std::cerr << e.what(); }
```

To reduce the number of catch-handler I would like to add inheritance from `std::exception`. But the problem with that is that it will "break" existing code. Namely the compiler will choose a different catch-handler than it did before:

```
try {
    SomeOtherLibraryFunction();
}
catch(std::exception const& e) { std::cerr << "STD-EX"; }
catch(MyException const& e)
{
    std::cerr << "LIBRARY-EX";
    ExecuteMandatoryCodeWhenMyExceptionGetsThrown(e);
}
```

As soon as `MyException` inherits from `std::exception` the second catch-handler will never be reached. The reason for that is stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch):

> When an exception of type E is thrown by any statement in compound-statement, it is matched against the types of the formal parameters T of each catch-clause in handler-seq, in the order in which the catch clauses are listed.

Is there a way that the compiler will take the catch-clause that is the best match instead of taking the first match? Or any other way to achieve the inheritance from `std::exception`without changing which catch-handler will be called?

Comment: Change the order of the catches?

Comment: Stop throwing exceptions altogether? :)

Comment: @Kilian Changing the order of the `catch` handlers is the only way.  It is best to order the handlers from specific types to generic types, not the other way around.  Then this would not even be an issue. In your first example, the `MyException` handler would always be executed whether `MyException` derived from `std::exception` or not.  But not so in your second example, the order of the handlers would need to be changed.

Comment: Consider renaming your class to something like `MyNewException` and completely take the declaration of `MyException` out of your libraries header file. This has the side-effect of breaking existing customers at *compile-time* who have written a `catch` statement expecting the old name rather than having to discover a subtle-side effect as a bug later.

Comment: @selbie How should he handle errors instead of throwing exceptions? I know you can return error codes but then your code will look like C code since you need to check for errors all the time.

Comment: @Damian - He would also have to write error free code. :)

Comment: @Damian - when there's a smiley emoticon next to a comment, it shouldn't be taken too seriously.   However, my second comment about not using an entirely different class name is for real. Matches identical to what the battlmonstr below was saying.

Comment: @selbie sorry missed the smiley ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way is to change the exception type to a new type in this case, e.g. `MyExceptionV2`, educate people that it is much better, and that `MyException` is going to be deprecated eventually. Then give them time to upgrade their catch blocks to use your new type and remove the extra catch blocks. Then deprecate it in the next version, then remove `MyException` in the later version.

Comment: I do not like that way because it means to support the old exception for a lot more releases. But I agree that it sounds very safe and will probably be the way I will do it. Thanks